# Using xindy with MiKteX (tex2xindy seems broken)

Tags: indexing, xindy

I'm trying desperately to use the `xindy` utility (v. 2.5.1, packaged on 2022-03-29) with the`imakeidx` package .
(Incidentally my aim is to use XeLaTeX, with the intent to create several indices using also non-latin scripts).

**EDIT:** All the relative questions on TeX.SE and other forums are obsolete and their proposed solutions don't work for me.

The LaTeX side works well, and in the (very) minimal case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % with XeLaTeX
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[program=texindy,options= -L french -C utf8]
\begin{document}
A \TeX\index{a} test\index{b}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

I get the expected `.idx` file, consisting in :

```
\indexentry{a}{1}
\indexentry{b}{1}
```

The problem occurs when running `texindy` or `xindy`, which never create a proper `.idn` file, the maximum that I can get is an empty index.

The command :

```
`texindy.exe -d script -d keep_tmpfiles -d level=3 -C utf8 -L french   -I latex -t testxindy.ilg testxindy.idx`
```

does no thing except to print :

`Calling xindy as: C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/scripts/xindy/xindy.pl -d script -d keep_tmpfiles -d level=2 -t testxindy.ilg -L french -C utf8 -M tex/inputenc/utf8 -M texindy -M page-ranges -M word-order -I latex testxindy.idx`

Running this command (whether or not I prepend `perl` and fix the space_in_path issue in various ways) does not work.
But calling `xindy.exe` with the above quoted arguments :

```
xindy.exe -d script -d keep_tmpfiles -d level=2 -C utf8 -t testxindy.ilg -L french  -M texindy -M page-ranges -M word-order -I latex -t testxindy.ilg testxindy.idx
```

gives a bunch of information, of which the relevant lines are:

```
concatenated xindy input file: "FXFmfaN5Gb"
Running filter: "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/scripts/xindy/../../miktex/bin/x64/internal/tex2xindy" <"FXFmfaN5Gb" >"2iExgBvNHa"
filtered xindy input file: "2iExgBvNHa"
Found language module C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/xindy/modules/lang/french/utf8-lang.xdy
xindy startup file: "wYayV891eS"
modules directory: C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/xindy/modules.
command: C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/scripts/xindy/../../miktex/bin/x64/internal/xindy-lisp.exe -M C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/scripts/xindy/../../miktex/bin/x64/internal/xindy.mem -E iso-8859-1 "wYayV891eS"
Opening logfile "testxindy.ilg" (done)
Reading indexstyle...
Loading module "lKuqmNCawW"...
... *(other modules)*
Finished reading indexstyle.
Finalizing indexstyle... (done)

Reading raw-index "2iExgBvNHa"...
ERROR: LOAD: A file with name 2iExgBvNHa does not exist
```

My conclusion is that **the `tex2xindy.exe` utility does not work. How to fix this ?**

With some variations of the command, or edited version of the perl scripts, the temporary "2iExgBvNHa" file is created but stay empty, and I get a `.idn` file containing only :

```
\begin{theindex}
  \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
  \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
      \par\textbf{#1}\par
      \nopagebreak
  }  
\end{theindex}
```

---

I'm running an up-to-date MiKTeX distribution under Windows 10(x64),
the `xindy` components are here :

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\scripts\xindy : the perl scripts texindy.pl, xindy.pl 
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64 : texindy.exe, xindy.exe, apparently wrappers to the formers
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\internal : tex2xindy.exe, xindy.mem, xindy-lisp.exe
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\xindy\modules : the folders of modules
```

and I have a [compact perl.exe (v5) executable](https://www.southsoftware.com/perl.html), which is in the path.

Comment: Consider switching to `upmendex`: https://ctan.org/pkg/upmendex

Comment: I would suggest upmendex instead too. But beside this: where are you when you start xindy and which shell do you use? (It works fine for me, but I see absolute pathes and not like you only relative ones: `concatenated xindy input file: "C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Documents\\Tests\\7b77nY5NN4"`

Comment: @Ulrike Thank you, II will have a look to this `upmendex` package. 

For the `xindy` issue : the result is the same either calling it by (Xe)LaTeX  (with -shell-escape) from `TeXworks` editor or from the Windows command line (`\system32\cmd.exe`) opened in the working directory. I'm not sure to understand your question/suggestions, as the other -randomly named -  temporary files are actually created in the working directory.

Comment: @Jhor I can only say that it works for me and that I have a slightly different output regarding the file names. But I have installed miktex only for me in user mode and not in shared mode. That could make a difference.

Comment: @ulrike @javier 
 `upmendex`works as a charm out of the box. Thanks! I simply patched `imakeleidx.sty` to add it as a valid `program` option alternative to `makeindex` or `(te)xindy`.